# Selenium webdriver click not working in Python :( (it used to)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was happily extracting information from a page, which requires clicking on a link to see the email. Everything was working fine until I turned off my laptop for a few days, I'm trying to do this task again but for some reason, it isn't working anymore :( (I never changed my code or anything). Please HELP!

Before anything, I tried to replace that click with Actions, tried to use Java, changed the webdriver, changed the waiting time, tried with CSS_SELECTOR, XPATH, etc (previously worked only with LINK_TEXT) but nothing I do seems to work. Here's my code, I censored my information:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/andre/Desktop/geckodriver'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://membership.icsc.com/login')
USERNAME = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
PASSWORD = 'XXXXXX'

#login first
login = driver.find_element(By.NAME, '_username').send_keys(USERNAME)
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, '_password').send_keys(PASSWORD)
submit = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div > div > div > div > div > div > form > div.text-center > p:nth-child(1) > button").click()
main = driver.get("THEURLISTOOLONGTOPUTITHERE")

#thescraper666

def get_scarping(link):
   driver.get(link)
   try:
       email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Click here to display email")))
       email.click()
       driver.implicitly_wait(5)
       email2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a').text
       print(email2)
  except NoSuchElementException:
     print("NO EMAIL")
  return driver.current_url 

links = ['A LIST WITH A BUNCH OF URLS']
scrapings = []
for link in links:
   scrapings.append(get_scarping(link))
```

Comment: Can you post the html code of the element in question.

Comment: Looks like they changed something on that page so that `'/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a'` very fragile absolute XPath get broken... Please show us the entire XML of that page if you can't share the credentials so we could login to that page ourselves and debug your code normally

Comment: @ArundeepChohan html for the hyperlink <a class="sc-fzoxKX craeZe" href="#">Click here to display email</a>   I think the problem is with that element, basically is not clicking it and going straight to the next step

Comment: @Prophet I don't really know how to do that :( my code is actually reading that line well but it's only printing "Click here to display email" since the previous step clicking step was ignored (email)